# MS SQL Server query that gives me all records LIKE each keyword from a list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm hoping someone can help me with a MS SQL Server query.  I have SQL 2017.  I have a comma delimitated string of keywords.  The string of keywords can be up to 50 keywords.  I know I could write a LIKE for each keyword but seems very lengthy.  Is there a better way or do I stick with the LIKE OR statements?

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
column LIKE ('%keyword1%') OR
column LIKE ('%keyword2%') OR
column LIKE ('%keyword3%') OR
column LIKE ('%keyword4%') 
... etc.
```

I have looked at the below query but this is where the column is an exact match not a `LIKE`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table
WHERE  column IN 
       ( SELECT convert(varchar, value) 
         FROM string_split('keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4', ',')
       )
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` in a join condition:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM some_table s
INNER JOIN
( SELECT convert(varchar, value) x
  FROM string_split('keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4', ',')
) t
ON  s.some_column LIKE '%'+t.x+'%'
```

It may not perform well on non-trivial volumes of data though. Consider using the full-text search feature.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help! Both suggestions did worked, however I ended up installing full text search and using the contains function.

Comment: what were the advantages of that? it definitely causes overhead, so how did you conclude that it was worth of the cost?

Comment: I would be interested to see if the indexes are used in your query, what indexes you got and if you manage to get index seeks, indexes scans, accurate memory grants, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual `VALUES` clause, or a temp table or table variable, in a join with `LIKE` as the join condition.

```sql
SELECT s.* 
FROM some_table s
JOIN (VALUES
  ('keyword1'),
  ('keyword2'),
  ('keyword3'),
  ('keyword4')
) t(x) ON s.some_column LIKE '%' + t.x + '%';
```